# Differences between the Battle Angel: Alita manga and anime and the Alita: Battle Angel Live action

Tags: battle-angel-alita

I've watched the Alita Battle Angel Live Action, and though I couldnt watch most of the anime yet it doesnt seem to be exactly the same story. For example, I believe in the manga she was named Alita after the doctor deceased cat and in the Live Action she's named so after his deceased daughter. Are there many differences like this? Which are the differences between the Battle Angel: Alita manga and anime and the Alita: Battle Angel Live action?